# Proper way to return elements of (ThisWorkbook.name) before the element of Format (Date)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, split

I have file with name `All PM 7.6 10-Jun v2` ,  **All PM 7.6** is a dynamic name and (10-Jun) is static name formulated using `Format(Date, "DD-MMM")` 
I want to get these elements (All PM 7.6) ,I tried the following:

```
Dim arrname, strExisting As String   
arrname = Split(ThisWorkbook.name, ".")
strExisting = arrname(0) & "." & arrname(1)
```

I think using  `arrname(0) & "." & arrname(1)` is not the proper way to get it ,as if this parts of name changed then I need to modify the code again.

In advance, thanks for all your help.

Comment: When you say "these elements (All PM 7.6)" do you want three of them, or the respective string?

Comment: @FaneDuru ,I need all elements before   Format(Date, "DD-MMM")

Comment: Three of them (for the string you show)? If so, in an array, or how else? Or only the string you show ('All PM 7.6')?

Comment: Will all the time those "elements" be three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not clarify (at least, for me) what is to be returned, please use the next function to extract the date string:

```
Function ExtractDateStr(strName As String) As String
    Dim arr: arr = Split(strName, " ")
    Dim strD As String: strD = arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
   
    ExtractDateStr = strD
End Function
```

It can be used in the next way, to return the prefix before the date string or each element up to it:

```
Sub testExtractWbNameElements()
   Dim x As String, strPrefix As String
   x = "All PM 7.6 10-Jun v2.xlsx"
   Debug.Print ExtractDateStr(x)
   strPrefix = left(x, InStr(x, " " & ExtractDateStr(x)) - 1)
   Debug.Print strPrefix 'the string before the date part
   
   Dim arrElem
   arrElem = Split(strPrefix, " ") 'each elements up to the date part, in an array:
   Debug.Print UBound(arrElem), Join(arrElem, "|") 'just proving the return...
End Sub
```

The above solution assumes that the elements before the date part may be different in terms of number. If only three, as in your example, the solution can be simpler..

**Edited**:

If the first elements to be returned will always be three, use the next simpler way:

```
Sub testSplitSpecElemNo()
   Dim x As String, arr
   x = "All PM 7.6 10-Jun v2.xlsx"
   arr = Split(x, , 4, 0) '4 means how many elements to return. First three and the last one (the rest all toghether) like the foourth
   arr(UBound(arr)) = "$#@%&" 'characters not very probable to exist like such a group in the other array elements...
   arr = filter(arr, arr(UBound(arr)), False) 'eliminate the last global one
   Debug.Print Join(arr, "|")
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, `arrElem` works correctly as I wish

Comment: @Waleed You did  not answer the clarification question: **Will all the time those "elements" be three?**... Are their number variable, as I supposed? If not, the solution would be much simpler.

Comment: Surely, the first elements to be returned can be varied on count (not always three) ,
Also I found out there is a space `“ “` at end of `arrElem` , I fixed it by **RTrim** on strPrefix line code (on your initial answer)

Comment: @Waleed You can easily solve the issue in the way the string is returned: `strPrefix = left(x, InStr(x, " " & ExtractDateStr(x)) - 1)`. In fact, I will adapt the code, anyhow... It is  not on my test to come with some corrections **after**. I even thought that the ending space may be useful, if a string is necessary, to probably be followed by something else, being already separated by a space... Then, I also tried designing the part involving an array return.